# Ajax $find after load

Tags: ajax

Hi we have a control that is added to the page after it has loaded, when we try to do  `$find(controlname)` it is returning null, is it possible to use `$find` to find controls that are added post page load, and if so how? if not does anyone have any suggestions as to an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Try someting like:

```
$("yourSelector").live("find", function() {
});
```